# How can I get result from group by on With clause(cte) in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I use this query for get these result :

code:

```
With Res
As
(
SELECT GroupID ,HV.[HadithVerID] As HadithId ,CenturyID
FROM JHadithVer HV 
INNER JOIN JHadith H ON HV.HadithID = H.HadithID 
    WHERE HV.SourceID=28
)
Select * From Res
```

Result:

```
GroupId Hadithid    CenturyId
7565    27062   4
22206   27063   4
125903  27064   6
60671   27065   4
125903  27074   4
125903  27083   4
```

How can I change my select of with(Res) for get HadithId that between common GroupId with less CenturyId. For example between

```
125903  27064   6
```

and

```
125903  27074   4
```

and

```
125903  27083   4
```

result is : **27074**(Between 2 result **27074** & **27083**, I want **27074** that is less!)

Comment: So, from the sample data you have provided you need only this record: `125903  27074   4` because there are other records with same `GroupID` but the `Hadithid` of this record is between others `Hadithid`'s?

Answer (score 1):

You just query your CTE result set like this:

```
SELECT 
  T.GroupID, 
  T.Hadithid, 
  T.CenturyID
FROM RES T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      T.GroupId, 
      T.CenturyID, 
      MIN(T.Hadithid) AS 'Hadithid'
    FROM RES T
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
          GroupID,
          MIN(CenturyID) AS 'CenturyID'
        FROM RES T
        GROUP BY GroupID
        ) T3 ON T3.CenturyID = T.CenturyID
    GROUP BY T.GroupID, T.CenturyID
    ) 
    T2 ON T.Hadithid = T2.Hadithid
WHERE T.GROUPID = 125903
```

Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1adf75/28).

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you.

```
With Res
As
(
SELECT GroupID ,HV.[HadithVerID] As HadithId ,CenturyID
FROM JHadithVer HV 
INNER JOIN JHadith H ON HV.HadithID = H.HadithID 
    WHERE HV.SourceID=28
)
Select  GroupID ,MIN(HadithId),CenturyID 
From Res
Group By GroupID,CenturyID
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as I understand, you need to rank your records and then select one with minimal rank for example. Ranking should be done in the following way: minimal rank for particular `GroupId` has record with minimal `Hadithid` for minimal `CenturyId`. You need only rank your records in CTE expression using ranking function `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
With Res
As
(
SELECT GroupID ,HV.[HadithVerID] As HadithId ,CenturyID,
       -- Add ranking
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY CenturyId, HadthId) AS RANK
FROM JHadithVer HV 
INNER JOIN JHadith H ON HV.HadithID = H.HadithID 
    WHERE HV.SourceID=28
)
Select * From Res
    WHERE RANK = 1    -- select all minimal values for every GroupId
```